# how to properly pass arguments to jq

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to add a json file's name as a key to the file structure itself. For example:

Input:

```
test.json 
{}
```

Output:

```
test.json
{
    "test": {}
}
```

These are the commands I'm trying:

```
output=`cat $file` | jq --arg fn "$file_name" '. += {"$fn" : {}}' 

or

# file_name already contains file name without extension
output=`cat $file | jq --argjson k '{"$file_name": {}}' '. += $k'`

echo "$output" > $file
```

However, the outputs are:

```
test.json
{
     "$fn": {}
}

test.json
{
     "$file_name": {}
}
```

How do I make sure `jq` can recognize args as a variable and not a string literal ?

Comment: Btw.: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: I assume your file contains more than an empty object? Because if not, then you could simply do `jq -n --arg fn "$file_name" '{$fn:{}}'` without any other input or `printf '%s' "$file_name" | jq '{(.): {}}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `input_filename` (and `rtrimstr` to remove the extension):

```bash
jq '.[input_filename | rtrimstr(".json")] = {}' test.json
```

Using `--arg` and a variable initialized from outside:

```bash
jq --arg fn "test" '.[$fn] = {}' test.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "test": {}
}
```

Comment: I think the empty object is supposed to be the file's contents, so `jq '{(input_filename | rtrimstr(".json")): .}' test.json`

Comment: @glennjackman Initially, I was also wondering whether `{}` stood for the input file's content, or some new content to be added to it. As OP's approach was `. += {"$fn" : {}}`, which uses `+=` to add to the existing file, I figured that it's probably the latter case, ie. the literal `{}` being (a placeholder for) new content. (Although not immediately obvious, my answer also adds to the old file, yet not by using `. += {…}` but by directly setting a field in the context object using `.[…] =` (assuming it is one, as is the sample content `{}`)).

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote them. Things in double quotes are strings. Also make sure your command substitution surrounds the correct expression and avoid useless use of cat. Still (double) quote your shell variables (single quotes prevent expansion).

```
output="$(jq --arg fn "$file_name" '. += {$fn: {}}' $file)"
```

or even:

```
output="$(jq --arg fn "$file_name" '.[$fn] = {}')"
```

The above assumes that your input file contains more than an empty object. Because if not, then you could simply do `jq -n --arg fn "$file_name" '{$fn:{}}'` without any input or `printf '%s' "$file_name" | jq '{(.): {}}'`

Comment: This doesn't remove the `.json` extension.

Comment: @Barmar why should it? The question doesn't ask about removing the extension and doesn't even mention anything about extensions. It only uses a variable `file_name` which I assume already has the correct value.

Comment: Look at the first example. The filename is `test.json`, but the key in the object is just `"test"`

Comment: @Barmar the only question in OP is still »How do I make sure jq can recognize args as a variable and not a string literal?«, _Not_ »my output contains the extension, how do I get rid of it?« Extension can be removed with jq or directly during parameter expansion in the shell (`"${x%.*}"`)

Comment: Yes, `file_name` already contains the name without extension. I edited to make that more clear.